Are there any US polls of whether Trump prosecution is considered politically motivated?
Were the American public (or a subset thereof) asked whether they consider prosecution of Donald Trump to be politically motivated? If so, what were the results?

People poll about everything related to politics so of course there are polls about this. And it should also be noted that people can think that the charges are politically motivated and that he did something wrong.
Half of Americans think Trump's guilty verdict was correct, should end campaign: POLL

Forty-seven percent of Americans said they think the charges against
Trump in this case were politically motivated, while 38% say they were
not. At the same time, the slight majority at 51%, think Trump
intentionally did something illegal in this case. Twelve percent think
Trump did something wrong but not intentionally, and 19% believe he
did not do anything wrong.


Majority believe prosecution of Donald Trump upheld rule of law, not motivated by politics However, if looking behind the title that makes it a very slim majority. Even more amusing is that this belief is correlated with one's political affiliation:

The truth is that with the role that Trumps plays in the US politics, and the clean party split during the impeachment proceedings, one should really ask whether anyone believes that the prosecution of Trump is not politically motivated? - that is, could Trump ever have a fair trial (could one really find jurors and judges whom he leaves impartial?)
It is also important to point out that politically motivated prosecution does not mean that Trump is innocent.
